# Trending Posts Mongoose efficient way to do it?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, data-visualization

How to do trending posts by views from a given day, month, etc and then make a data visualization in each post.

I thought about adding timestamps to each view but I don't know if it will be efficient and if it is the way to do something like this(If I would go with this solution, how much more space it would take in DB?).

Every time a user hits post URL, I add +1 to views and set a cookie to not add views on refresh by the same user. and then I save final to MongoDB.
for example how to achieve something like on NPM site with downloads data visualization

**My Schema**

```
const postsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  category: String,
  shortDesc: String,
  className: String,
  description: String,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  hidden: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  nsfw: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  comments: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'App',
    },
  ],
  user: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
    username: String,
    country: String,
  },
  meta: {
    downloads: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    fav: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    views: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  versions: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Version',
    },
  ],
  lastUpdate: Date,
});
```